# Cordova InAppBrowser loaderror event not firing for Error 500

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I have an issue with InAppBrowser. I am trying to catch errors that might come from the website I'm loading and I'm simulating this by a faulty .htaccess, which produces an error 500.

I have the following code:

```
ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open($openuri, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no,zoom=no,enableviewportscale=no,disallowoverscroll=no');
ref.addEventListener("loadstop",function() {
        .....
    });
ref.addEventListener("loaderror",function() {
        alert('Toot');
    });
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
        .....
});
```

The website is opening and all the "loadstop" and "loadstart" events work correctly. However, when I deliberately make the page return an "error 500", the event "loaderror" is not firing.

It does fire for other errors - like when there is no internet on the phone.

Any ideas as to why this is happening are highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you testing on Android device?

Comment: Looking at InAppBrowser Plugin code for Android, it interally user onReceivedError method for handling 'loaderror' event.  So i looked at this issue from webview perspective and stumbled on this link - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=968 which states that onReceivedError function is not meant to catch HTTP errors. For HTTP error handling, we may have to use 'onReceivedHttpError' function which is not part of the plugin. Hope it makes sense as to why this is not working.

Comment: @Gandhi yes, that explains it. If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks

Comment: Done.you can accept it. Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at InAppBrowser Plugin code for Android, it interally uses `onReceivedError` method for handling `loaderror` event.  So i looked at this issue from webview perspective and stumbled on this link - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=968 which states that the `onReceivedError` function is not meant to catch HTTP errors.

For HTTP error handling, we may have to use `onReceivedHttpError` function which is not part of the plugin. I hope it makes sense as to why this is not working.

Comment: @Frighi I feel it still handles only the errors relates to web resource not http errors

Comment: @GSH I remember editing the inAppBrowser plugin, but I do not have access to the fix and I do not recall where I did the change, sorry.

Comment: @DreamWave, if you recall that you had some add kind of this function

public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse)

To InAppBrowser.java, as the function posted in the comment below.

Comment: public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorRes) {
            super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorRes);
            try {   JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                obj.put("type", LOAD_ERROR_EVENT);
                obj.put("url", request.getUrl().toString());
                obj.put("code", errorResponse.getStatusCode());
                obj.put("message", "GSH Error!");
                sendUpdate(obj, true, PluginResult.Status.ERROR);
            } catch (JSONException ex) { LOG.d(LOG_TAG, "Error Mag"); } }

Comment: yes, what you said is right, but did you try Http plugin to catch that 500 status code errors ? @Gandhi..

 
iam handle myself 500 status code error using Http Plugin. it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ionic 4 and I couldn’t manage to make the solution based on config.xml editing to work :

preference name="ErrorUrl" value="myErrorPage.html"/

Placing an addEventListener on loaderror didn’t work neither. It looks like it is not triggered by http errors and the plugin need a fix.

But we found a hack that is much simpler.

On loadstop we wait 500 milliseconds and then we get the loaded url by triggering executeScript with and window.location.href

If the loaded url is of the custom error page, in Cordova (not in IAB) we display a custom message with a back button.

It's a hack but that cover the requirement for now