# Ionic 3 InAppBrowser not firing event

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I am making an ionic app where I need to call to a website(not exist). I am just trying to catch that into the error. But the "exit" event does not get fired.

Code

```
this.browser = this.iab.create("http://www.randomwebsite.com/", "_blank", this.options);
    this.browser.on('exit').subscribe(event => {
        console.log("exit -->", event);
    }, err => {
        console.log("InAppBrowser exit Event Error: " + err);
    });
```

It opens the browser in the app but only shows the 404 page, but dont go further in the error code, so that I can handle it.

Comment: Maybe this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37763998/316738

Comment: @Matt, I think its related to that issue as you suggested from this case, but do you know if there is some work around to it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this plugin, but from [reading the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/) , it looks like getting the httpstatus isn't something you can do (I may be wrong) and a status other than 200 won't throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Declare cordova in your component

`declare var cordova;`

Then for the error check you can use the following function

```
const browser = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://randomwebsite.org', '_blank', this.options);

browser.addEventListener('loadstart', function(e) {
  // event fires when the InAppBrowser starts to load a URL.
  console.log(e);
});

browser.addEventListener('loaderror', function(e) {
  // event fires when the InAppBrowser encounters an error when loading a URL.
  console.log(e);
  browser.close();
});
```

You can checkout the documentation [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser).

Comment: When I do this way in Ionic 3 on a mobile phone, then it gives the error: cordova is not defined. I think cordova object is not available globally in ionic 3?

Comment: Did you add this line `declare var cordova;` in your component?  Place it before the `@component` decorator.

Comment: Yes I added     declare var cordova;

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly then the main problem is to catch the error

```
this.browser = this.iab.create("http://www.randomwebsite.com/", "_blank", this.options);
    this.browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(event => {
        console.log("exit -->", event);
    }, err => {
        //once the page loading stops and there is an error it comes here and displays you log.
        console.log("InAppBrowser exit Event Error: " + err);
    });
```

exit event is fired when we exit the inAppBrowser